# Download XML from a URL without having special characters in it

Tags: java, xml, apache-commons

this is my Code to Download an Xml

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

String fileURL = "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/16160/000001616016000061/calm-20160528.xml";
URL url = new URL(fileURL);
File file = new File("/home/user1/Downloads/calm-20160528.xml");
FileUtils.copyURLToFile(url, file);
```

but this Downloaded XML is having Special Character like this

```
&lt;/td&gt;
                &lt;td valign="middle" style="width:09.78%;border-top:1pt solid #000000 ;border-left:1pt none #D9D9D9 ;border-bottom:1pt none #D9D9D9 ;border-right:1pt none #D9D9D9 ;background-color: #CCEEFF;height:15.00pt;font-family:Times New Roman;font-size:11pt;text-align:right;" nowrap="nowrap"&gt;437,556&amp;nbsp;
```

i want to get rid off these special characters on Downloading this XML itself..

Comment: It seems to me that the part of the downloaded XML which you're speaking of is HTML. `</td><td valign="middle" ...` are fragments of HTML.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem with FileUtils.copyURLToFile. The XML itself contains these characters.
It seems some XML-Tags contain html, and this is quoted for not confuse with the xml. You have to unquote the html.

Answer (score 0):

This file is a valid XML-document, including escaped XML fragments.
So it is valid "as is". If you want to process it, use a XML-parser and unescape the escaped XML fragments.